# How to calculate option premium stop loss if underlying reaches a certain value near the strike price given the current implied volatility

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes

I have sold a put option. The market is likely to open negative on Monday, the expiry of option is on Thursday. I have a certain stop loss level in my mind to exit this position if the index reaches that value. How can I determine the SL for the option premium?

```
Real numbers:
current index value: 19530
Strike sold 19300 Put
Premium received: 25 (on Friday, towards the end of the session, expiry in the next coming Thursday)
rate = 0
IV = 10.23


Stop loss on Index = 19400
```

How to calculate the stop loss on option premium for this? If I try to enter stop loss index, strike, rate,IV in black Scholes formula, it may not adjust that well to the implied volatility that would follow if index reaches 19400 as well the gamma spike.

How do you usually approach this to get a genuine stop loss on premium value